# cx_Freeze Exe Application closes as soon as opens

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.5, cx-freeze

I am trying to just convert my pygame python project to a .exe file using cx_Freeze. The setup file executes correctly and without error, but the issue is that when I run my .exe file the console window will open and close and my game window will not appear.

The setup.py I am using:

```
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\MY_USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Users\\MY_USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"

import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("main.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(

    name="Shooty",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages": ["pygame"], "include_files": ["character.png"]}},

    description="Shooty, An epic platformer!",
    executables=executables

)
```

I had a TCL error so I added the first three lines. Then after that everything should be correct. I have already seen similar posts but none seem to help. 
[cx_freeze app opens then closes quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313188/cx-freeze-app-opens-then-closes-quickly) < This user just has a simple typographical error
[python program works but .exe does not open cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35141781/python-program-works-but-exe-does-not-open-cx-freeze) < Has no anwser, and no helpful comment. 
 
[Executable generated with cx_freeze opens for an instant before closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027829/executable-generated-with-cx-freeze-opens-for-an-instant-before-closing) < This user actually gets an error. I don't.

**To clarify/TLDR:**
I am using cx_Freeze to convert a pygame game to .exe format. I only have one image called character.png. The build executes perfectly without errors (as long as I include the first three lines, which I have) The only issue is: upon running the exe, the console opens but not my game window and the console closes immediately.

Comment: Anyone have any solution?

Comment: Try running the executable from the command line. The console won't close immediately that way, so if there are any error messages, you'll be able to read them

Comment: OK, just did that. Console has no output.

Comment: Are you loading a font from a TTF file? You could also try adding `import pygame._view` to your source code as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309981/pygame-compiling-to-exe-with-cx-freeze). I kind of doubt that either of these would help since you're getting no output at all, but it's worth trying.

Comment: No, I followed the post anyway to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied your setup script and tested it with one of my own Pygame projects. It didn't work for me either at first, so I investigated the problem and found a bug on Bitbucket: [https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/211/if-**name**-**main**-doesnt-work-in](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/211/if-__name__-__main__-doesnt-work-in)

Apparently there is a bug, specifically with cx-Freeze version 5.0, that the line `if __name__ == "__main__":` will not work. But when I replaced it with `if __name__.endswith('__main__'):` as suggested in the bug report, then my Pygame app worked with cx-Freeze, so this fixed the problem for me.

In addition, I would suggest adding the keyword argument `base="Win32Gui"` to `cx_Freeze.Executable`, so that the console window doesn't show up behind the Pygame window, unless if you want it. Also, Tkinter is completely unnecessary for a Pygame app, so you can add `"excludes": ["Tkinter"]` (or lowercase `tkinter` in Python 3) to the options dict and get rid of the first three lines of your script.

Comment: I noticed that with the Win32Gui option (I haven't tested without it) in Task Manager the EXE stays running even after closing the Pygame window. It may be necessary to add a sys.exit() call to fix this.

Comment: Edit: never mind, I got it to work using your solution and messing around a bit. Thanks! This has been more trouble than its worth,

Comment: The issue was fixed apparently (I have the same error but no fix for me): https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/commits/90829a1fba648fc9fd798afdfae14a2edcdc4b53